# i want to get the one key from multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have one multi-dimensional array of category and sub-category.
i want to get 'id'of every category and subcategory form array.
my array is like this.

> Array
>   (
>       [1] => Array
>           (
>               [id] => 14
>               [name] => Category 1
>               [parent_id] => 13
>               [sub_menu] => Array
>                   (
>                       [2] => Array
>                           (
>                               [id] => 15
>                               [name] => Category 2
>                               [parent_id] => 14
>                               [sub_menu] => Array
>                                   (
>                                       [6] => Array
>                                           (
>                                               [id] => 19
>                                               [name] => Category 6
>                                               [parent_id] => 15
>                                               [sub_menu] => Array
>                                                   (
>                                                   )
>                                           )
>                                   )
>                           )
>                       [4] => Array
>                           (
>                               [id] => 17
>                               [name] => Category 4
>                               [parent_id] => 14
>                               [sub_menu] => Array
>                                   (
>                                   )
>                           )
>                   )
>           )
>   )

```js
public function get($data)
    {
        foreach($data as $key=>$value1)
        {
            if($key=='id'); 
              {
                $data= $value1['id'];
              }
            if(is_array($key))
            {
                $data=$this->get($kay);
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
$val=$this->get($data);
print_r($val);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above you are looping through (and so touching each element in the array), but each time you do this:

```
$data= $value1['id'];
```

or this:

```
$data=$this->get($kay);
```

(which, incidentally, mis-spells `$key` as `$kay`)

you overwrite the value of `$data`. So a best case scenario is that you get the last $id that is covered.  (You also got your keys and values and arrays mixed up at various times.)

Assuming that you want a flattened array at the end with all those arrays, something like this would probably do it (this is not meant to be running code - you will need to do some debugging):

```
public function get($data)
    {
        if ($data['id'])
            $rtn = array($data['id']);
        else
            $rtn = array();
        foreach($data as $v)
        {
            if(is_array($v))
            {
                $rtn = array_merge($rtn, $this->get($v));
            }
        }
        return $rtn;
    }
$val=$this->get($data);
print_r($val);
```

Although this application is not particularly difficult, writing recursive functions is not a starting skill in any kind of programming. Since it seems you are still a little hazy on how to process arrays (without recursion) it may be that it would be worthwhile to work through some tutorials.